# "Download as PNG" of plotly scatterplot in shiny app, does not work in RStudio

Tags: r, download, shiny, png, plotly

Hello I would like to be able to locally download as png the plot that I created in this shiny app. When Im trying to use the default plotly otion to download the file I take a file named "AAAAAAAAAAAA" which is incorrect. Is this happening due to the rest of my code or is a general plotly issue? Can I download it ?

```
#ui.r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel(div("CROSS CORRELATION",style = "color:blue")),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Input CSV-File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

      # Input: Select separator ----
      radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                   choices = c(Comma = ",",
                               Semicolon = ";",
                               Tab = "\t"),
                   selected = ","),


      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
      radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                   choices = c(Head = "head",
                               All = "all"),
                   selected = "head")





    ),
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Table",
                           shiny::dataTableOutput("contents")),
                  tabPanel("Correlation Plot",
                           tags$style(type="text/css", "
           #loadmessage {
                                      position: fixed;
                                      top: 0px;
                                      left: 0px;
                                      width: 100%;
                                      padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
                                      text-align: center;
                                      font-weight: bold;
                                      font-size: 100%;
                                      color: #000000;
                                      background-color: #CCFF66;
                                      z-index: 105;
                                      }
                                      "),conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",
                                                          tags$div("Loading...",id="loadmessage")
                                      ),
                           fluidRow(
                             column(3, uiOutput("lx1")),
                           column(3,uiOutput("lx2"))),
                           hr(),
                           fluidRow(
                             tags$style(type="text/css",
                                        ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
                                        ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
                             ),
                           column(3,uiOutput("td")),
                           column(3,uiOutput("an"))),
                           fluidRow(
                           plotlyOutput("sc"))
      ))
  )))
#server.r
function(input, output) {


  output$contents <- shiny::renderDataTable({

    iris
  })


  output$lx1<-renderUI({
    selectInput("lx1", label = h4("Select 1st Expression Profile"), 
                choices = colnames(iris[,1:4]), 
                selected = "Lex1")
  })
  output$lx2<-renderUI({
    selectInput("lx2", label = h4("Select 2nd Expression Profile"), 
                choices = colnames(iris[,1:4]), 
                selected = "Lex2")
  })

  output$td<-renderUI({
    radioButtons("td", label = h4("Trendline"),
                 choices = list("Add Trendline" = "lm", "Remove Trendline" = ""), 
                 selected = "")
  })

  output$an<-renderUI({

    radioButtons("an", label = h4("Correlation Coefficient"),
                 choices = list("Add Cor.Coef" = cor(subset(iris, select=c(input$lx1)),subset(iris, select=c(input$lx2))), "Remove Cor.Coef" = ""), 
                 selected = "")
  })  


 output$sc<-renderPlotly({

   p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = input$lx1, y = input$lx2))+

     # Change the point options in geom_point
     geom_point(color = "darkblue") +
     # Change the title of the plot (can change axis titles
     # in this option as well and add subtitle)
     labs(title = "Cross Correlation") +
     # Change where the tick marks are
     scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 2.5, 30)) +
     scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 2.5, 30)) +
     # Change how the text looks for each element
     theme(title = element_text(family = "Calibri", 
                                size = 10, 
                                face = "bold"), 
           axis.title = element_text(family = "Calibri Light", 
                                     size = 16, 
                                     face = "bold", 
                                     color = "darkgrey"), 
           axis.text = element_text(family = "Calibri", 
                                    size = 11))+
     theme_bw()+
     geom_smooth(method = input$td)+
     annotate("text", x = 10, y = 10, label = as.character(input$an))
   ggplotly(p1) %>%
     layout(hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white", 
                              font = list(family = "Calibri", 
                                          size = 9, 
                                          color = "black")))

 }) 




}
```

Comment: For me, the download works in the browser but not in the RStudio viewer. Have you tried both?

Comment: yes that works.tnx

Answer (score 2):

I believe to export plotly as a .png, you need to use the plotly_IMAGE function. Further guidence of how to do this can be found here towards the bottom: https://plot.ly/r/static-image-export/

e.g.

`library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(x = c(1,2,3,4), y = c(2,4,1,3), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
plotly_IMAGE(p, format = "png", out_file = "output.png")`